# transform a 2 dimensional ode 1 system to 2nd order one dimension system

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

Given a matrix $M$ of $2 \times 2$, and an ode: $$y'=My$$
let $y=(v_1,v_2)$.
find a second order ode such $v_1,v_2$ are solutions.

Comment: I thought about finding eigen vector, got very complex formula, and nothing to advance from there. I also tried multiple version of guessing with e, no luck either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $y'=My$. I consider $M = \begin{bmatrix}m_{11} &m_{12} \\ m_{21} &m_{22}\end{bmatrix}$, and the solution is $y =\begin{bmatrix} v_1\\ v_2\end{bmatrix}$. This gives us the equations

$$\begin{cases}v_1'= m_{11}v_1+m_{12}v_2 \\ v_2'= m_{21}v_1+m_{22}v_2 \end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}v_1''= m_{11}v_1'+m_{12}v_2' \\ v_2'= m_{21}v_1+m_{22}v_2 \end{cases} $$

Therefore $v_2 = \frac{v_1'-m_{11}v_1}{m_{12}}$ and $v_2' = \frac{v_1''-m_{11}v'_1} {m_{12}}$, substituting these two equations in the second equation we get

$$\frac{v_1''-m_{11}v'_1} {m_{12}}=m_{21}v_1+m_{22}\times\frac{v_1'-m_{11}v_1}{m_{12}} \\ \Rightarrow  v_1''=(m_{11}+m_{22})v_1'+(m_{22}m_{11}-m_{21}m_{12})v_1 \\ \Rightarrow v_1'' - \text{tr}(M)v_1'+\det(M)v_1=0$$

The same equation arises for $v_2$ also.

Now that I think about it, this result is obvious (have you noticed the Cayley-Hamilton equation), consider the further analysis below

$$y'=My \Rightarrow Dy=My \Rightarrow (DI_2-M)y=0 \Rightarrow \det(DI_2-M)y=0 \\ \Rightarrow ((D-m_{11})(D-m_{22})-m_{21}m_{12})y=0 \Rightarrow y'' - \text{tr}(M)y'+\det(M)y=0$$

Where $D$ is the differentiation operator and $I_2$ is the two by two identity matrix. Which means you were right, eigenvalue equation of the matrix is now obvious.

Comment: amazing, can you explain how you figured it out?

Comment: Thank you, but there is nothing special above to be honest, this type of calculations are common in ODE books, for example see chapter 7 of "Differential equations with applications and historical notes" by G.F.Simmons.